# Remove rows based on date column [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to filter for `customer_id's`that first appear after a certain date in this case `2019-01-10` and then create a new df with a list of new customers
df

```
date          customer_id

2019-01-01    429492
2019-01-01    344343
2019-01-01    949222
2019-01-10    429492
2019-01-10    344343
2019-01-10    129292
```

Output df

```
customer_id
129292
```

This is what I have tried so far but this gives me also customer_id's that were active before 10th January 2019

```
s = df.loc[df["date"]>="2019-01-10", "customer_id"]

df_new = df[df["customer_id"].isin(s)]
df_new
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean indexing with filtering with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

mask1 = df["date"]>="2019-01-10"
mask2 = df["customer_id"].isin(df.loc[~mask1,"customer_id"])

df = df.loc[mask1 & ~mask2, ['customer_id']]
print (df)
   customer_id
5       129292
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

cutoff = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-10')
mask = df['date'] >= cutoff

customers_before = df.loc[~mask, 'customer_id'].unique().tolist()
customers_after = df.loc[mask, 'customer_id'].unique().tolist()

result = set(customers_after) - set(customers_before)
```

Answer (score 0):

"then create a new df with a list of new customers" so in this case your output is null, because 2019-01-10 is last date, there is no new customers after this date

but if you want to get list of customers after certain date or equal than :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'date':['2019-01-01','2019-01-01','2019-01-01',
            '2019-01-10','2019-01-10','2019-01-10'],
    'customer_id':[429492,344343,949222,429492,344343,129292]
})
certain_date=pd.to_datetime('2019-01-10')
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df=df[
    df.date>=certain_date
]
print(df)


           date  customer_id
3 2019-01-10       429492
4 2019-01-10       344343
5 2019-01-10       129292
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `'date'` column has datetime objects you just have to do:

```
df_new = df[df['date'] >= datetime(2019, 1, 10)]['customer_id']
```

If your `'date'` column doesn't contain datetime objects, you should convert it first it by using [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) method:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

And then apply the methodology described above.